# Is it a bad idea to build integration tests purely with Javascript and run in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, integration-testing

We are experimenting with different methods of integration testing. One option we thought of was to build something purely in Javascript and run in the browser. These tests would use jQuery to navigate and fill the DOM and then run simple comparisons to return true or false.

We built something quickly to try the idea and it works well. We run the script in the console of a browser. We created several identical tests with Capybara and Selenium and our method runs just as fast.

I searched and couldn't find anyone else doing this and was wondering if there is something I'm not realizing that makes this a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Many libraries do it: [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) and [JSUNIT](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) are two examples

But you can use [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) to do a lot of it without JavaScript.